# How to concatenate values of duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, concatenation

When reading a csv into a javascript dictionary, how can I concatenate values of what would otherwise be duplicate keys? I've seen answers for how to do this with bash, c#, and perl, but I haven't been able to find answers for Javascript. Here's what I have:

```
var subjects = {};

d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
      subjects[data[i].Id] = data[i].VALUE;    
  }
  console.log(subjects);
});
```

This, obviously writes over existing keys. Instead, I want the key to be an array of the values. The csv basically looks like:

```
Id, VALUE
id1, subject1
id2, subject1
id1, subject3
```

And I want to output as:

```
{"id1": ["subject1", "subject3"], "id2": ["subject1"]...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if your output already has the key, if so you add the new value to the array. Else you create an array.

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {
    var subjects = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        // Check if key already exists
        if(subjects.hasOwnProperty(data[i].Id)){
            // push data to array
            subjects[data[i].Id].push(data[i].VALUE);
        }else{
            // create new key and array
            subjects[data[i].Id] = [data[i].VALUE];
        }
    }
    console.log(subjects);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it into an array and then push the content into that array
var subjects = {};

```
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
  {
      //first time we see this id, turn it into an array
      if(typeof subjects[data[i].Id] != "object"){
        subjects[data[i].Id] = [];
      }
      //push content to the array
      subjects[data[i].Id].push(data[i].VALUE); 
  }
  console.log(subjects);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the `for` loop:

```
typeof subjects[data[i].Id] == 'undefined' && (subjects[data[i].Id] = []);      
subjects[data[i].Id].push(data[i].VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the footprint of your code slightly if you use `reduce`:

```
var out = data.reduce((p, c) => {
  const id = c.Id;
  p[id] = p[id] || [];
  p[id].push(c.VALUE);
  return p;
}, {});
```

RESULT

```
{
  "id1": [
    "subject1",
    "subject3"
  ],
  "id2": [
    "subject1"
  ]
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2a6yq22s/)